# DEBUG: Send: QUIT Failed to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 [SMTP: Failed to connect socket: Connection refused (code: -1, response: )]

Tags: php, sockets, email, ssl, pear-mail

I'm trying to send an email using PHP script that I'm hosted on Godaddy hosting. I'm using Pear Mail() function to send emails, but now I'm getting an error `code: -1, response:`

**Error:**

> ```
> DEBUG: Send: QUIT
> Failed to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 [SMTP: Failed to connect socket: Connection refused (code: -1, response: )]
> ```

**My PHP Script:**

```
<?php
require_once "Mail.php";
session_start();
   define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
    define('DB_USERNAME', 'userName');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'Password');
    define('DB_NAME', 'DB_Name');
 
    /* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
    $link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
     
    // Check connection
    if($link === false){
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }else{

    $sponcer_id = rand(111111,999999);
    if(isset($_POST['fullname']) && isset($_POST['mobile_no']) && isset($_POST['confirm_password'])){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO register_form (Sponcer_id,refer_id, full_name,mobile,email,password,state,country)
                    VALUES ('".$sponcer_id."', '".$_SESSION["refer"]."', '".$_POST['fullname']."','".$_POST['mobile_no']."','".$_POST['email_id']."','".$_POST['confirm_password']."','".$_POST['state']."','".$_POST['country']."')";
            if ($link->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                $from = 'test@gmail.com';
        $to = $_POST['email_id'];
        $subject = 'Registration Email';
        $body = "Welcome... Your UID =><strong>".$sponcer_id."</strong>";

        $headers = array(
            'From' => $from,
            'To' => $to,
            'Subject' => $subject
        );

        $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
            'SMTPAuth' => true,
            'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
            'port' => '465',
            'auth' => true,
            'encryption' => STARTTLS,
            'debug' => true,
            'username' => 'test@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'password'
        ));
        
        //$params['debug'] = 'true'; // Create the mail object using the Mail::factory method
                //$mail_object =& Mail::factory('smtp', $params); // Print the parameters you are using to the page

        $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

        if (PEAR::isError($mail))
        {
            echo('<p>' . $mail->getMessage() . '</p>');
        } else {
            echo('<p>Message successfully sent!</p>');
        }
                // echo "Welcome .... your UID =><strong>".$sponcer_id."</strong> <a href='mainregister.php' class='btn btn-info'><< back</a>";
                  
                //header('Location: register.php');
            } else {
                $_SESSION['message'] = "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;         
            }
    } 
    }
?>
```

**I've referred this link:**
[Send email using the GMail SMTP server from a PHP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-the-gmail-smtp-server-from-a-php-page)

Any kind of help is welcome. Thanks in advance.